# Shiny: Warning: The select input contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance

Tags: r, shiny

I have a table, which contains 1500 columns. When I tried to use shiny to get the `colnames`, I got the following warning:

> The select input contains a large number of options; consider using server-side selectize for massively improved performance.

So I replaced `varSelectInout` and `updateVarSelectInput` to `varSelectizeInput` and `updateVarSelectizeInput`. But the warning is still there. I don't know how to get rid of the warning and improve the performance.

Here is my example:

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "rawFile", label="File"), 
  varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = "")
  plotOutput("box")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  df <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$rawFile
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = T)
  })
  
 observeEvent(df(),{
    updateVarSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", data = df())
  })
  
 

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: did you try to set `server = TRUE` in `updateSelectizeInput` : see [server side selectize](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `server = TRUE` as suggested by @Waldi and `session`

Here is the full code using Selectize

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "rawFile", label="File"), 
  varSelectizeInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = ""),
  plotOutput("box")
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  df <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$rawFile
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = T)
  })
  
  observeEvent(df(),{
    updateVarSelectizeInput(session, inputId = "getColumn", data = df(), server = TRUE)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```